# Xcode displays "Reomving cached front buffer" in the debug log

Tags: swift, wkwebview

iOS17, Swift, using WebKit.

I have an app using `WebKit` and recently, I see thousands of entries like this:

```
Reomving cached front buffer 1873
Reomving cached front buffer 1873
Reomving cached front buffer 1877
```

This seems like a recent new behavior (perhaps because I upgraded from Xcode 14.3 to Xcode 15?)

I don't know if the loaded-page (or URL) the cause, or if this is just some undocumented background behavior being logged. I googled and searched here (note the specific spelling), and found no previous discussion.

Here's the log snippet leading up to the errors, which seemed to run until I turned off the simulator.

```
<WKNavigationAction: 0x11f058600; navigationType = -1; syntheticClickType = 0; position x = 0.00 y = 0.00 request = <NSMutableURLRequest: 0x600000028d40> { URL: https://m.stripe.network/inner.html#<stuff removed> }; sourceFrame = <WKFrameInfo: 0x119c35c70; webView = 0x12106e800; isMainFrame = NO; request = <NSMutableURLRequest: 0x6000000281d0> { URL: https://js.stripe.com/v3/m-outer-93afeeb17bc37e711759584dbfc50d47.html#<stuff removed> }>; targetFrame = <WKFrameInfo: 0x119c4ca30; webView = 0x12106e800; isMainFrame = NO; request = <NSMutableURLRequest: 0x600000028dc0> { URL:  }>>
Reomving cached front buffer 1873
Reomving cached front buffer 1873
Reomving cached front buffer 1877
```

I've tried to isolated and reproduce the problem, but I don't have a lot more information at the moment... I'll add more info as I go.

What does this message mean? In this case, I have some control over the web content, so this is sub-optimal, I might be able to address it by changing the content server.

Comment: Please share a [example].

Comment: The problem is not consistently reproducible... since the typo is so obvious, I'd assume that even the original coder and tester didn't see this very often.

I updated the question, I'd like to get a clear technical description of what is begin logged, so I can take any appropriate action.